# insertAdjacentHTML почему не безопасно?

Tags: javascript, безопасность

Смотрю видео по JS и наткнулся на тот пункт что использование `insertAdjacentHTML` не безопасно
Но не могу понять почему...
 **JavaScript** при загрузке используется у каждого юзера локально, так в чём проблема безопасности использования `insertAdjacentHTML`?

Comment: в этом видео разве не описывается почему небезопасно? :-)

Comment: @Grundy он говорил что какой нибудь хакер может через такую штуку например майнер вставить, но я всё равно не понимаю как. 
(Если не брать тот вариант что хакер сервер взломает,тогда и разницы то особой нет что я использовал, если у него доступ к исходному коду есть)

Comment: все упирается в то, откуда берется html, который вставляется этой функцией